# Is this query valid or is the script wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hey i'm having some troubles with my query in mysql. This script should (i hope) check if my query is valid. However it all ways outputs false and i'm pretty sure my query is valid. Can someone help explain to me why.

```
<?php
require "connect.inc.php";
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
if ($query_run){
    echo "Correct";
} else{
    echo "False";
}

?>
```

Comment: Check your database connection

Answer (score 3):

```
else{
    echo "False";
}
```

Is useless

```
else{
    echo mysql_error();
}
```

Will tell you what the problem is. Whatever we will do is guesswork.

Comment: I changed it to that and this error came up about the new line `Fatal error: Call to undefined function msql_error() in C:\xampp\htdocs\programs\anbu\test.php on line 8`

Comment: Its mysql_error not msql_error

Comment: The error shows no database selected however i thought this was a correct way of doing that `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);
mysqli_select_db($conn, $database);`

Comment: See there you go. Your connection is with ***mysqli*** but query is with ***mysql*** api. Please look at http://www.php.net/mysqli_query

Comment: Okay i've managed to fix it now thanks a lot for the help